# Java - ClassNotFoundException I have the class included, but why do I get an exception?

Tags: java

```
public static Reservation[] openBinaryFile( String fileName )
{
    Reservation [] objArray = null;

    try
    { 
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream( fileName ) );

        objArray = (Reservation[])inStream.readObject();

        inStream.close();
    }
    catch( ClassNotFoundException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "Exception: ClassNotFoundException." );
    }
```

I have the class included, but why do I get an exception? The class is in the same package as the others. Why am I getting this exception?

EDIT: Here is the stack trace
run:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Reservation
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:604)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1575)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at myViewer.DatabaseFile.openBinaryFile(DatabaseFile.java:42)
        at myViewer.Viewer.(Viewer.java:175)
        at myViewer.Viewer.main(Viewer.java:188)

Comment: Your catch clause discards all the crucial information, namely WHICH CLASS was not found, and which statement caused the exception.  Try printing the stack trace instead and post the result.

Comment: Something isn't right about this example.  If the JVM didn't know what `Reservation` was, it wouldn't get past the array declaration.

Comment: You're not currently printing out the contents of the exception, which means you don't really know what class isn't being found. Maybe it's something the serialized file depends on. In general, when you catch an exception and log it you should almost *always* print out the exception message.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I am not sure, but in theory a missing dependency would rather have given a `ClassDefNotFoundError` or the compilation would just have failed, because the same class is already imported.

Comment: I've included the stack trace. I'm pretty sure it's Reservation it is not being able to find. I did include the original Reservation file.

Comment: They are apparently not of the same version. Recompile and copy exactly the same class file at both sides and/or include a `serialVersionUID` as per `java.io.Serializable` javadoc in the class file at the both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- Make sure that you're actually reading `Reservation[]`

  - If you're reading a subtype of `Reservation` (e.g. `VIPReservation`) then you need the binary for that type
- Make sure it's the same exact version of `Reservation`

Immediate actionable:

- Diagnose the stack trace.

---

Looking at the stack trace, it expects `Reservation` to be located in the *default package*. Make sure that this is the case.

Comment: The first would have given a `ClassCastException` rather than `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: But he could've been reading `VIPReservation[]`, for which he does not have the binary, right?

Comment: I'm sure I wrote out Reservation [] and am trying to read in Reservation [].

Comment: "The class is in the same package as the others." -- is it the default package? Because the stack trace suggests that's where it needs to be.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, all. Didn't realize the previous package had to be the same.

Comment: It has to be the same exact version of the same exact class. Refactoring to another package effectively results in a different class. Also, reminder: use of default package should be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The class file in question is not of the same version as the class file from which the instance was originally serialized. Align it out or give them both the same `serialVersionUID`.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is giving you the exception? An `e.printStackTrace()` will tell you. Maybe you didn't `import java.io.ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: That would have given a compilation error rather than a runtime exception.